# Comma for multi values in the ASP.net MVC Form, but if one value contain comma as well

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a web form, in this webform i have multiple input with the same name.

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Object", Method.Post))
   {
foreach(var prop in Model.Properties)   
{%>
    <div id="prop-<%= prop.name %>">
        <input name="<%= prop.name%>" value="" type="text" />

    <% if(prop.type == "Lines") 
       {%>
        <input type="button" value="Add More" onclick="$('#prop-<%= prop.name %>').append('<input name=\'<%= prop.name%>\'></input>');" />
     <%}%>
  <%}%>
```

now in C# I get the result like this

```
var result = "item_name1,item_name2,item_name3"
```

but if the user enter a comma in one field for example field 2, the result will be:

```
var result = "item_name1,item,name2,item_name3"
```

and now I can't know what is the correct input

Note: I can't use objects and Models but only FormCollection, Thanks in advance

My C# Code:

```
[HttpPost]public ActionResult Edit(string ObjectId, string Code, FormCollection form){
        foreach (var key in form.AllKeys)
        {
                var prop_name = key;

                var property = db.Properties.First(prop => prop.Name == prop_name);
                if (property.ReadOnly == true)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                string EmptyValue = property.EmptyValue;

                //for lines we need to split the incoming value
                var values = form[key].Split(',');
                int rowNo = 0;
                foreach (var value in values)
                {
                    var temp = new DI_Value();
                    //Here we get value according to it's data type
                    temp.Value = GetValue(value, property.DataType); 
                    PropertyName = prop_name;
                    temp.RowNumber = rowNo++;
                    temp.DataType = property.DataType;
                    temp.EmptyValue = EmptyValue;

                    data.Add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

And I'm using Json to send data to the server:

```
    $.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: submit_url, data: $(form).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                setStatusMsg(result.error_text, 'error');
            }
            else {
                setStatusMsg(success_message, 'success');
            });
```

The logic is to get the form and save it to XML file, but all fields are dynamics for that i can't use Models

Comment: I don't know, but if there is no solution i will force the user to type (or replace comma on change event with) &comma

Comment: You need to change your logic a bit.I dont see sending form data in one string with `,` seperated is a useful thing to do..Could you show us yor `c#` code as well as how your posting data to backend..we may suggest you some better way to Post your form data... :)

Comment: You could use some sort of escape sequence to escape the comma?

Comment: @user1042031 thanks for your replay, I will post my `C#` code

Comment: @MohamedNoor : as well as the way you send data to your `c#` code.

Comment: @user1042031 Thank's again for your replay, I send data using JSON. (Sorry if my post was not clear enough but this is the 1st question for me in stackoverflow)

Comment: Why don't you use view models? FormCollection should be avoided. You said that the field name and value are dynamic. There's nothing preventing you from using custom objects with properties such as Name and Value and then have a collection of those objects, ... The default model binder will then automatically take care of everything so that you don't need to do manual parsing.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov , I thought I can't use classes becuase in Html i need to put the name of the property, and how the MVC will make the mapping between the values and class has two properties (Name, Value). could you provide an example? Thank you very much

Comment: Just follow the standard conventions and create view models:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx. I can't provide an example because I don't know what you are trying to achieve. You haven't explained how is the data generated in the view, what makes it dynamic, and how it needs to be outputted in the resulting POST action. Until those points are clarified there's no much help that I can provide.

Comment: @ekolis thank's for your replay, I mentioned that is the last solution is to escape the comma before sending it to the server. but it's really not cool solution for me :-)

Comment: Hi @DarinDimitrov I changed the html code, and this is the way how I generate the View. Thanks in advance for your help